# getToken() only gives refresh token

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on an Android App that logs in Gdrive service and after asking the user for giving permissions, it saves the token and send it to our backend that is the one which asks the gdrive service itself for the content. Before, I was using AccountManager to log in but few weeks ago I got an email from Google asking to move the Authorization process to Google play services libraries. I am having problems getting the token, here is my code:

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(myApp.getApplicationContext(), DriveScopes.DRIVE);

Account[] mAccounts = credential.getAllAccounts();
```

After selecting the account to login, the listener makes this:

```
Account account = mAccounts[position];
credential.setSelectedAccountName(account.name);
new GetDriveServiceTask().execute(credential);

private class GetDriveServiceTask extends AsyncTask<GoogleAccountCredential, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(GoogleAccountCredential... credentials) {
            try{
                 GoogleAccountCredential credential = credentials[0];
                 String token = credential.getToken();
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                  UserRecoverableAuthException exception = (UserRecoverableAuthException) e;
                  Intent authorizationIntent = exception.getIntent();
                  startActivityForResult(authorizationIntent,REQUEST_PERMISSIONS); 
            }
```

I am having the problem when the user gave access to his/her account before, the command credential.getToken(); only gives me what I think is refresh token, something like: "1/SGvUDUNnRG8wVs_REISKx1xuupbwAKeEQ5fHXH-rbOk"...how can I get the access token from this?

I tried making the Post call to the url "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" as described here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh but I am getting unauthorized_client every time...

Please I am stuck here and the email said, the AccountManager method will stop working 1st February...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

You should authorize using Google Play Services and that will only give you an access token.
For an example of how to authorize your Android app with Google Play Services in order to send requests to the Drive API, check the following quickstart guide:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue.  This is not the answer to the question that was asked!  I have been searching for a solution to this for several days and all I find are dismissive answers like this from Google engineers.